# adjust alignment of dropdowns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem adjusting my dropdowns to equally aligned to my textarea.

Html:

```
<!-- YEAR -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, ViewBag.years as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                             "-- Select Year --", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cbYears" })


                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                </div>


                <!-- MONTH -->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Month, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, ViewBag.months as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                                            "-- Select Month --", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cbMonth" })


                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<!-- GOOD -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-1">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Good, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-push-1">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Good, new { maxlength = 5000, rows = "10", cols = "200", id = "txtGood" })
                        @*@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Good, new { maxlength = 5000, id = "txtGood" })*@
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Good, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I just want to adjust my Month,Geography and Process dropdowns to push a little bit more to the right so it aligned to my textarea.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlv8p.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think your .col-md classes have default bootstrap padding or margin.
So you can add the ".nopadding" class to a particular .col-md div to remove it.

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```